# dynamically changing HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

Is there a way to dynamically update an HTML tag?

The HTML tag I have is:

```
<p id=something>hello</p>
```

Is there a way through JavaScript that I can change `hello` to another value.

What is the best way to go about changing that value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = 'Something New';
```

Comment: Perfect! Don't know how I didn't stumble across that, but thank you!